# C3W2_Assignment in coursera Deep Learning course NLP

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, nlp

## grader-required-cell

## GRADED FUNCTION: tokenize_labels

def tokenize_labels(all_labels, split_labels):
"""
Tokenizes the labels

```
Args:
    all_labels (list of string): labels to generate the word-index from
    split_labels (list of string): labels to tokenize

Returns:
    label_seq_np (array of int): tokenized labels
"""

### START CODE HERE

# Instantiate the Tokenizer (no additional arguments needed)
label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()

# Fit the tokenizer on all the labels
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(all_labels)

# Convert labels to sequences
label_seq = label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(split_labels)

# Convert sequences to a numpy array. Don't forget to substact 1 from every entry in the array!
label_seq_np = np.array(label_seq)-1 <----------- i don't know what is wrong


### END CODE HERE

return label_seq_np
```

the output is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
label_seq_minus_one = [[num - 1 for num in seq] for seq in label_seq]

label_seq_np = np.array(label_seq_minus_one)
```